# Scrapy - can't write to log in spider's __init__ method

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to write to the log in the `__init__` method of my spider, but I can't seem to get it working despite it working fine from the parse method.

The call to self.log within the init method is made by the method 'get_urls_from_file'. I know the method is being called because I see the print statement in the stdout, so I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. I am using scrapy v0.18. Thanks!

My code is below:

```python
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy_redis import connection
from importlib import import_module
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.settings import CrawlerSettings

class StressS(BaseSpider):
    name = 'stress_s_spider'                                                    
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']

    def __init__(self, url_file=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StressS, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        settings = CrawlerSettings(import_module('stress_test.settings'))
        if url_file:
            self.url_file = url_file
        else:
            self.url_file = settings.get('URL_FILE')
        self.start_urls = self.get_urls_from_file(self.url_file)
        self.server = connection.from_settings(settings)
        self.count_key = settings.get('ITEM_COUNT')

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('Processed: %s, status code: %s' % (response.url, response.status), level = log.INFO)
        self.server.incr(self.count_key)

    def get_urls_from_file(self, fn):
        urls = []
        if fn:
            try:
                with open(fn, 'r') as f:
                    urls = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
            except IOError:
                msg = 'File %s could not be opened' % fn
                print msg
                self.log(msg, level = log.ERROR)
        return urls
```

Comment: Where do you want to use `self.log` int your `__init__` method?

Comment: Was just editing the question to reflect that - Within init, I make the self.log call in the get_urls_from_file method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `start_requests` method:

```
    # Default value for the argument in case it's missing.
    url_file = None

    def start_requests(self):
        settings = self.crawler.settings
        url_file = self.url_file if self.url_file else settings['URL_FILE']
        # set up server and count_key ...
        # finally yield the requests
        for url in self.get_urls_from_file(url_file):
            yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
```

Also you could override the method `set_crawler` and set up there the attributes:

```
    def set_crawler(self, crawler):
        super(MySpider, self).set_crawler(crawler)
        settings = crawler.settings
        # set up start_urls ...
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable workaround, esp the set_crawler approach given similar needs. Just out of curiosity, do you know why writing within the init method wont work? Is it because the logs aren't initialized for writing at the time it is called?

Comment: @user2871292, the spider is instantiated very early and thus you can't access many objects that are not set yet, like self.crawler.

Comment: In modern Scrapy versions [`from_crawler`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.from_crawler) should be used instead of `set_crawler`.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy 0.22
It looks impossible.